# jQuery, change 5 items at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have markup like this:

```
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
<li class="supress hidden"></li>
```

I can remove the class="hidden" by writing:

```
if ($('.supress').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.supress').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

**Edit:** Before I tried:

```
if ($('.supress:lt(5)').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.supress').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

But what do I do if I only want to remove the "hidden" class from the the first five items?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [**$.slice**](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to cut the first 5:

```
$('.supress.hidden').slice(0, 5).removeClass('hidden');
```

While you can use `:lt` selector for the same result, it's not recommended on [**its own page**](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

> Because `:lt()` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. **For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead**.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(".supress.hidden:lt(5)").removeClass('hidden')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get elements with more than one class, so you don't need to check if has class or not.

```
$('.supress.hidden').slice(0,5).removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.supress').each(function(i){
     if(i < 5 && $(this).hasClass('hidden')){
          $(this).removeClass('hidden');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides lots of ways to do this:

- Look at the [jQuery methods for Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/). In particular, you can use [the .slice() method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)
- Look at the advanced [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). In particular, ['.supress:lt(5)'](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).